# ...vs VTE(next to)

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern

What do these letters and numbers below represent? After you've figured that out, replace the three question marks!

LXE 329, CIE 266, PNS 260, KPE 141, HCQ 132, LZE 122, FVS 111, DIG 101, VTE 100, DBE ???

Hint

> Look again and step back a **little**. This applies to one of the two.

Note: You'll find this online!

EDIT: Just to clarify; "(next to)" refers to "VTE" and not "...vs VTE"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the letters are all

> currencies

Based off your hint:

> "Stepping back a little" & taking the previous letter for each letter in the question gives:
> **LXE** -> KWD (Kuwaiti Dinar)
> **CIE** -> BHD (Bahraini Dinar)
> **PNS** -> OMR (Omani Rial)
> **KPE** -> JOD (Jordanian Dinar)
> **HCQ** -> GBP (Pound Sterling)
> **LZE** -> KYD (Cayman Islands Dollar)
> **FVS** -> EUR (Euro)
> **DIG** -> CHF (Swiss Franc)
> **VTE** ->   USD (US Dollar)
> **DBE** -> CAD (Canadian Dollar)

Going off your title:

> The numbers relate to 1 unit of each currency compared to the USD (minus the decimal mark), which is why VTE 100 (100 = 100).
> Your comment pointed me to [this website of the top ten highest currencies this year](https://fxssi.com/top-10-of-the-strongest-world-currencies-in-current-year). It has the conversion rates as of 20 January 2020 with the CAD coming in tenth.

Using this idea for DBE should mean the ??? is:

> 075

Comment: This is correct! Even though not *exactly* the number i'm looking for. If you search for rot13("gbc 10 pheerapl va gur jbeyq"(gur yrggref naq ahzoref ercerfrag gung yvfg) lbh'yy frr n fcrpvsvp yvfg!)

Comment: I'm glad I was on the right track. I figured my date was probably going to let me down. Cool puzzle to get me through the end of the work day, but now I'm disappointed that BVE didn't make that list

Comment: Well, maybe it will by the end of the year :)

Comment: @ItsPete Good job :)